# Spring Security hasIpAddress giving 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying my hands on Spring Security for the first time. I have created a simple application where I am trying to whitelist my localhost IP.

I have created the following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1");
}
}
```

However, when I am calling my API from the postman, I am getting 403 Error Code. What am I doing wrong here? Please guide.

Comment: I am simply calling localhost:8080/

Comment: @dur using 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 worked fine. Thanks :)

Comment: It's really problematic calling this problem a duplicate due to its MANY MANY sources for the error..................

Comment: I got a similar problem and fixed it by putting `    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()..access("hasIpAddress(\"127.0.0.1\") or hasIpAddress(\"::1\")");` so it resolves both IP4 and IP6. Otherwise using only 127.0.0.1 was giving me 403 in my browser when accessing as `localhost`

Comment: @AkhilPrajapati I had the same issue but I couldn't solve it. Is it possible to write its full code if you don't mind?